# contentView frame size is not as the cell size created for the UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift3, uicollectionview

I'm using a UICollectionView where I'm defining the sizeForItemAt returning a CGSize basically doing a math regarding the view width.

In my cell, I have an UIImageView, the UICollectionView cellForItem calls my initialization method of the cell class. On this initialization class I set the frame width to contentView.frame.width, also set contentMode to scaleAspectFill and added clipsToBounds.

However, my UIImageView is always the same width as the contentView frame doesn't seem to get the size I determined on the sizeForItemAt on the creation of the UICollectionView. The cell is indeed the size I determined, but when I access the contentView.frame it is not there.

Any help?

Thanks a ton,

Comment: what size you want for image view?

Comment: the imageview should have the same width as the cell size.
the problem is when I try to get the contentview size, which is supposed to be the same size as the cell size I define, it always gives me the same number, doesn't matter the screen size as it seems the cell layout I did is not being applied, dimensioned to the cell size.

Comment: You doing from storyboard or coding?Why don't you just give view.frame.width in sizeForItemAt method

Comment: if doing from storyboard you can set image view accordingly if doing from coding set width frame as view.frame.width

Comment: Well, I think that's the way to go, using the view.frame.width to set the image view size as well the cell. Thanks, Tushar

Comment: np glad i helped